# ppl_detection package and training data

Tags: ros, people

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you know if you have to train ppl_detection package or should work at it's best out of the box. Because I get very poor results. Almost every object is human.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/31544/ppl_detection-package-and-training-data/) by [Grega Pusnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1849/grega-pusnik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 460 on 2012-04-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its labelling everything as a person for me as well (see the image).

But I have a solution, don't use ppl_detection, use [openni_tracker](http://ros.org/wiki/openni_tracker) with the latest openni and nite libraries instead. It can automatically find people, is orders of magnitude more accurate than [ppl_detection](http://ros.org/wiki/ppl_detection) and tracks skeleton data too. [This](http://igorbarbosa.com/articles/how-to-install-kin-in-linux-mint-12-ubuntu/) is a good tutorial on how to set it up.

[image description http://imageshack.us/a/img593/3188/humans.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img593/3188/humans.jpg)

---

Originally posted by [James Diprose](https://answers.ros.org/users/3239/james-diprose/) with karma: 123 on 2012-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0